# Limit of the function, $f(x)=\frac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos x}{x^4}$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Tags: functions

I tried solving the above through L'Hospital's rule but the computation becomes complicated. Help me solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor expansion method: 
$$\cos x \approx 1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4+ o(x^4)$$
$$\sin x \approx \frac{1}{1!}x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3 + o(x^3)$$
$$\cos \left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right) \approx 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{5}{24}x^4 + o(x^4)$$

$$= \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left[1-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{5}{24}x^4-\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{4!}x^4\right)\right]}{x^4}\right) = 1/6$$

L'Hopital's Rule Method
$$\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{\cos \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)-\cos \left(x\right)}{x^4}\right)$$
Apply the rule
$$=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\cos \left(x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)}{4x^3}\right)$$
Apply the rule
$$=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-\cos ^2\left(x\right)\cos \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)+\sin \left(x\right)\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)+\cos \left(x\right)}{12x^2}\right)$$
Apply the rule
$$=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{3\cos \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)+\cos ^3\left(x\right)\sin \left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{24x}\right)$$
Apply the rule
$$=\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{-6\cos^2(x)\sin(sin(x))\sin(x)+4\cos^2(x)\cos(\sin(x))-3\sin^2(x)\cos(\sin(x))-\sin(x)\sin(\sin(x))+\cos^4(x)\cos(\sin(x))-\cos(x)}{24}\right)$$
Now you can delete the part of the limit 
where there is the $\sin$ multiplied with other values, because we know that the $\sin$ of $0$ is $0$....So it will be 
$$\lim _{x\to \:\:0}\left(\frac{4\cos ^2\left(x\right)\cos \left(x\right)+\cos ^4\left(x\right)\cos \left(x\right)-\cos \left(x\right)}{24}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Comment: Any other method other than expansion?

Comment: I think it's the easiest way ... you can not just settle for asymptotic approximations

Comment: @Drishtinarula, the question is about understanding the local behavior of a function near a point.  The function is nonlinear and complicated, so it is easier for the human mind to decompose this function into more transparent summands first.  The Taylor expansion is just one of the many possible ones; what is key is that it is an *asymptotic expansion*; i.e., the higher-order terms are the ones with a clearly smaller contribution.

Another way (nonanalytical) could be geometric; i.e., constructing diffeomorphisms.  But when you try, you end up with... expansions.:)

Comment: As in can't we come up with the answrr by applying l'hopital's rule?

Comment: @Drishtinarula Check my try with L'hopital's rule

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use 
$$\cos A-\cos B=2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{B-A}{2}$$
Thus we have

$$\cos \sin x-\cos x=2\sin\frac{\sin x+x}{2}\sin\frac{x-\sin x}{2}$$

Using $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$
We see that 
$$\frac{\sin\frac{\sin x+x}{2}}{x}=\frac{\sin\frac{\sin x+x}{2}}{\frac{\sin x+x}{2}}\frac{\sin x+x}{2x}\rightarrow 1$$

And using $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\rightarrow \frac{1}{6}$
$$\frac{\sin\frac{x-\sin x}{2}}{x^3}=\frac{\sin\frac{x-\sin x}{2}}{\frac{x-\sin x}{2}}\frac{x-\sin x}{2x^3}\rightarrow \frac{1}{12}$$

Thus the final answer is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\cos(\sin x)-\cos(x) = \int_{\sin x}^{x}\sin(t)\,dt \tag{1}$$
is the integral of a function that behaves like $t$ in a neighbourhood of the origin, over an interval whose length behaves like $\frac{x^3}{6}$ as $x\to 0$. Stating the same with rigor, $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$ implies
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(\sin x)-\cos(x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{x-\frac{x^3}{6}}^{x}t\,dt = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x^2}{72}\right) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

*$cos a- cos b=-2(sin(\frac{a+b}{2})sin(\frac{a-b}{2}))$

**$x-sinx \sim \frac{x^3}{6}$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{cos(sinx)-cosx}{x^4}=\\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{-2sin(\frac{sinx+x}{2})sin(\frac{sinx-x}{2})}{x^4}=\\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{-2sin(\frac{2x}{2})sin(\frac{\large \color{red} {-\frac{x^3}{6}}}{2})}{x^4}=\\\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{(-2x)(-\large \frac{x^3}{12})}{x^4}=\\
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{(+\large \frac{2x^4}{12})}{x^4}=\\\frac{1}{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try l'Hôpital once:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin(\sin x)\cos x+\sin x}{4x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}\biggl(\,
  \underbrace{\frac{\sin(\sin x)(1-\cos x)}{4x^3}}_{(1)}-
  \underbrace{\frac{\sin(\sin x)-\sin x}{4x^3}}_{(2)}\,\biggr)
$$
Now we can try the two pieces separately.

### Limit of (1)

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\sin x)(1-\cos x)}{4x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}
\frac{1}{4}
\frac{\sin(\sin x)}{\sin x}
\frac{\sin x}{x}
\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}
$$

### Limit of (2)

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\sin x)-\sin x}{4x^3}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{4}\,
  \underbrace{\frac{\sin(\sin x)-\sin x}{\sin^3x}}_{(2.1)}\,
  \underbrace{\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}}_{(2.2)}
$$
The limit of (2.2) is $1$; for (2.1) we can do the substitution $x=\arcsin t$ and get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\sin x)-\sin x}{\sin^3x}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t-t}{t^3}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\cos t-1}{3t^2}=-\frac{1}{6}
$$
Therefore we conclude that the limit of (2) is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)=-\frac{1}{24}
$$
Thus our original limit is
$$
\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{24}=\frac{1}{6}
$$